# Filling up 2 images in a custom tableview is not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I am working with a webservice to get my data for in my application. I get different wallpapers images back as you can see over here.

```
"wallpapers": [

    {
        "url": "http://www.krcgenk.be/files/wallpaper/app/iphone4_fans.jpg"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://www.krcgenk.be/files/wallpaper/app/iphone4_logo.jpg"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://www.krcgenk.be/files/wallpaper/app/iphone4_simaeys.jpg"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://www.krcgenk.be/files/wallpaper/app/iphone4_trainers.jpg"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://www.krcgenk.be/files/wallpaper/app/iphone4_vossen.jpg"
    }

]
```

As you can see, at the moment the amount of wallpapers is an odd number. so one cell in the tableview only contains 1 image instead of 2. I tried to do the following.

```
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSInteger count = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

        if (_loopIndex < count)
        {
           NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_loopIndex inSection:0];
            _loopIndex++;
            NSIndexPath *path2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_loopIndex inSection:0];
            Wallpaper *wallpaper1 = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:path];
            Wallpaper *wallpaper2 = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:path2];

            NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:wallpaper1.url]];
            UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
            NSData* imageData2 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:wallpaper2.url]];
            UIImage* image2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData2];

           if(!(image == nil)){
                cell.img1.image = image;
           }else{
               NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.krcgenk.be/files/wallpaper/app/iphone4_logo.jpg"]];
               UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
               cell.img1.image = image;
           }
            if(!(image2 == nil)){
               cell.img2.image = image2; 
            }else{
                NSData* imageData2 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.krcgenk.be/files/wallpaper/app/iphone4_logo.jpg"]];
                UIImage* image2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData2];
                cell.img2.image = image2;
            }
        }
        _loopIndex++;
        if(_loopIndex >= count){
            _loopIndex = count-1;
        }

        return cell;
```

It fills up the four first images correctly in my imageView but it crashes on the fifth one. This is the error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[_PFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (5) beyond bounds (5)
```

Kind regards and thanks in advance

EDIT

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

        NSInteger count = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
        return count;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table view is expecting 6 rows. but your data source array contains only 5 items. check `- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView` delegate method of table view.

Comment: I've edited my question. should I just add another row to it ?

Comment: sectionInfo is your data source. NSlog [sectionInfo count] and check.